# Trying to build a "add to cart" button connected to SQLserver

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to make a add to cart button in my ProductView.aspx. When user browse the Products and click on them there will be an add to cart button next to a picture. Every information about the product are stored in SQL with the name 'tblProducts'. The user will choose a size and then press "Add to cart".
I have made two new tables in SQL named 'tblCart' and 'tblPurchase' where the items will be added.
The error that appears is

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and it complains about this line of code

```
Int32 UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["USERID"].ToString());
```

I know the its empty and I don't seem to make SQL to understand that I want to add data to the tblCart...
Here is the full code for the add button.

```
protected void btnAddtoCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64 PID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["PID"]);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblCart where PID='" + PID + "'", con))
            
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Int64 updateQty = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[0][8].ToString());
                        Int64 UserID = 0;
                        Int64.TryParse((String)Session["Username"], out UserID);
                        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RayOfbDB"].ConnectionString))
                        {

                            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblCart SET Qty=@Quantity WHERE PID=@CartPID", con1);
                            cmd1.Connection = con1;
                            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updateQty + 1;
                            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@CartPID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PID;
                            con1.Open();
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();                                
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Int64 UserID = 0; 
                        Int64.TryParse((String)Session["Username"], out UserID);
                        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RayOfbDB"].ConnectionString))
                        {
                            string sqlQuery = "insert into tblCart values (@UID,@PID,@PName,@PPrice,@PSelPrice,@Qty)";
                            SqlCommand Cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con2);
                            Cmd2.Connection = con2;
                            Cmd2.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserID;
                            Cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CartPID;
                            Cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = myPName;
                            Cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PPrice", SqlDbType.Money).Value = myPPrice;
                            Cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PSelPrice", SqlDbType.Money).Value = myPSelPrice;
                            Cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "1";
                            con.Open();
                            Int64 CartID = Convert.ToInt64(Cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PselPrice, myPselPrice etc is a misspelling that I use also in SQL. So its misspelled everywhere.

EDIT: I updated the code to cmd.Parameter.Add instead and can now see the values PName PPrice etc doesn't have any contact. Any suggestions how to fix that?
[image]

Comment: You clearly know *how* to parametrise, so why do you choose to not to in one of your statements? Also, you should really be using `Parameters.Add` rather than `Parameters.AddWithValue`. [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/2018/02/), [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: At this point, your problem is not unrelated to SQL. You - for reasons no one can help you with - don't have session variable with that name. You know that - so fix it. Your logic seems to depend on having a value for that and you cannot move forward without fixing that missing value.

Comment: And you are using cmd, but not cmdU or myCmd. Same for con1 and con (2 different variables with same name btw). Why (really, why not)?

Comment: Im very new to this(started 3 weeks ago) I really want to learn `Parameters.Add` but in my case i don't know what to write because of the first error i can't see if it works or not.

I'm not using cmd? can i remove them or? i just followed a guide who were somewhat similar but i guess was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When Session["USERID"] is null you will have this problem of System.NullReferenceException because you are trying to convert a null value to string and after that to Int32.

So I think you must verify if Session["USERID"] is not null before doing that.
Try to debug this session variable to verify if it has some value.

Comment: yeah, I most been so tired last night. USERID is the variable that points towards the name of the "logged" in user. In my SQL that name was "Username" so I changed it and that error seems gone. But i got this instead
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.''
at 
`Int64 UserID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["Username"].ToString());`

Comment: Use a Int64.TryParse to verify the value passed. It returns true if it was converted successfully and false if its not. It is very likely that Session["Username"].ToString() is not a numeric value, maybe it has some letters or special characters. Try to debug or write this variable to see it.

Comment: So i changed the code like the other comments wanted me to. I can see that all the names CartPID to myPSelPrice "does not exist in the current context". how do i fix that?  I update the code above and add a picture of my SQL table